# prepending a variable output PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This is probably really basic and my first PHP question on here but here goes...

I'm working with WordPress and trying to output ACF data assigned to the current user.

So far I have:

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
    echo the_field('price_list', 'user_$current_user->ID'); ?>
```

So basically, the output of wp_get_current_user is e.g. `2`, but ACF needs to be passed the value as e.g `user_2`... so my question is how can I prepend the `user_` to the `2`?

I'd rather add it in at the output stage rather than adding it to the variable if that makes sense, as the variable is used elsewhere too.

Comment: "user_".$variable i guess using the dot

Comment: Go read up on language basics: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php, http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use string concatenation:

```
echo "user_".$current_user->ID;
```

So in your example and specifications you would use it like this:

```
echo the_field('price_list', 'user_'.$current_user->ID);
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? 

`<?php echo the_field('price_list', '"user_".$current_user->ID'); ?>`

Still doesn't seem to work...